# MKAnnotationView - Callout title or description with multiple lines?

Tags: ios, mkannotationview

Is it possible to display several lines in title or description/subtitle without writing your own custom annotation view, using i.e. MKPinAnnotationView?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's not possible.

What you need is to create a custom callout, and layout it the way you want. You can even mimic the native appearance.
This page can help you creating the custom callout: http://blog.asolutions.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-1/